What type of wire is this
I have been doing Stem creates with my kids. One of them is missing the red splitter wire to connect the battery pack to the DC motor. There is an equivalent black one that is connected in the image. I would like to order a replacement, but I am having a hard time identifying the wire and what to order.
Right now I just direct connected to one motor, but need the splitter to connect both.


The "Dupont" pin is 0.025" square, fits snugly in a 0.040" hole; other square pins also exist, with other dimensions.   Instead of connectorized wiring, it can be wire-wrapped (usually using 30 gage Tefzel insulated wire).

The "official" name for that type of connector is Dupont. You should be able to find various kits and individual assemblies through a quick internet search. Quality will probably be low, but the proper tool costs several thousand dollars. Your kids may also learn the important engineering principle of "don't expect quality electrical components from Amazon".

Hahaha. Oh man. I’m gonna steal that.

"that type of connector is Dupont" - I agree it's very likely, but it might be best to check the size before ordering more parts—unless the OP has a soldering iron to join wires with one connector to a wire with a different connector. Which will soon be a new acquisition in electrical circuit investigations :)

@Samsamplus "dupont y cable splitter" is the term to search for.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні Naming it "the wrong crimper" might be too cryptic for a newcomer to electronics ;)

I was able to find the part online ty all!  I really appreciate you all!


Search again for the missing item.
Contact the vendor to obtain the missing item.
You can use a different colour splitter—the colour of the wire insulation is only for humans to be able to differentiate wires - the copper inside is the same.
"dupont y cable splitter" is the term to search for.


I was just hoping to figure out what the wire was called to order one. I am a complete newbie.

@SamPlusPlus There isn't a particular name for two wires going into one connector - if you gave us a link to the website of the kit then we could help you identify what they call it. Also, you could edit your question to give us the dimensions of the exposed pin on the wires—you might need a caliper to measure the diameter accurately, if you have one available (or a micrometer, of course)—and then perhaps someone could suggest a way of making your own.

I see, thank you. I didn't realize that. I'll do more digging.

Search for Dupont splitter on Amazon and you will find a few.

When I need to make wires like that, I use a kit from Pololu.
They have both pre-crimped wires, and the housings you push them into. (Although in your case, each housing you need is just 1x1)
Unfortunately, Y splitting is not standard, so you'll need to cut and splice two red wires into one Y, with the right kind of end each side.
I'm not attached to the company in any way, I just like their no-nonsense high-quality products.
https://www.pololu.com/product/3342
https://www.pololu.com/product/1900
If you're not good with the cutting/splicing/soldering, though, this option won't work for you.
